# Build instant search query

Tags: outlook, vsto

I know I can use `explorer.Search(filter, scope)` to search outlook using instant search. But it's overwriting existing query in instant search.

Is it possible to read existing query from search box, or add more text to it? Similar to what existing buttons in search ribbon are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent of Explorer.Search is only to automate searching in the UI.  Unfortunately you cannot work with the results nor obtain the current search query.

What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: My intention is to add a button to search ribbon (to refine search group) that will refine search criteria in similar manner as other buttons in that group (which means it will add additional filter to existing query).

Comment: In that case you'll have to recreate the existing search UI and add your own custom buttons to them.  Since you can't read any of the settings, you'll have to execute all of them yourself.